# angularjs scope function of a repeated directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to have a directive with a repeat on it and have it call a function on the parent control as well as child controls. however when I add a scope: { function:&function}
the repeat stops working properly.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lhenning/4a1ywcan/9/)

the main.html is something like

```
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>
        <ul>
        <name-row ng-repeat="media in mediaArray" on-delete="delete(index)" >
        </name-row>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
var module = angular.module('my-app', []);

function MainController($scope)
{
    $scope.mediaArray = [
        {title: "predator"},
        {title: "alien"}
    ];
    $scope.setSelected = function (index){
        alert("called from outside directive");
    };
    $scope.delete = function (index) {
        alert("calling delete with index " + index);
    }

}

module.directive('nameRow', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
         priority: 1001, // since ng-repeat has priority of 1000
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.setSelected = function (index){
                alert("called from inside directive");
            }
        },
        /*uncommenting this breaks the ng-repeat*/
        /*
        scope: {
        'delete': '&onDelete'
        },
        */
        template:
'            <li>' +
'                <button ng-click="delete($index);">' +
'                    {{$index}} - {{media.title}}' +
'                </button>' +
'            </li>'
    };
});
```

Comment: You could create a Factory or a Service, that will have this functions, and you can use it everywhere.

Comment: but what I want to have is the parent be able to specify the function through attribute <directive onDelete="function I want"> If I use a service I am just making a global function but I can't reuse the directive with a different function. I have to make a new function or am I missing something

Comment: Ok. Now I got what you want. You tried to take out `(index)` from `on-delete="delete(index)"`? Te way you are doing will pass a function that would execute and couldn't be used in your template.

Comment: How about this way; put the `ng-repeat` in your directive template? ~ https://jsfiddle.net/4a1ywcan/10/

Comment: Also, when calling the function in your directive, you need to use an object to name the arguments, ie `delete({index: $index})`

Comment: I am still confused as to why when I uncomment the scope does the media title not show up?

Comment: @Phil I am looking for something like the hide dialog example at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive  Only inside a repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As klauskpm said is better to move common logic to an independent service or factory. But the problem that i see is that the ng-repeat is in the same element of your directive. Try embed your directive in an element inside the loop and pass the function in the attribute of that element or create a template in your directive that use the ng-repeat in the template

```
<li ng-repeat="media in mediaArray" >
    <name-row on-delete="delete(media)" ></name-row>
</li>
```

Comment: this seems to fix the problem moving it out of the directive but I am still looking for why.

Comment: As i understand it has to do with directive priority. I think that ng-repeat is terminal. meaning that it is trigger when all the other directives attached to your html element already were triggered

Answer (score 0):

As I've suggested you, the better approach to share methods is building a Factory or a Service, just like bellow:

```
app.factory('YourFactory', function(){
    return {
        setSelected: function (index){
            alert("called from inside directive");
        }
    }
};
```

And you would call it like this:

```
function MainController($scope, YourFactory) {
    $scope.setSelected = YourFactory.setSelected;
    // Could even use $scope.yf = YourFactory;, and call yf.setSelected(index);
    // at your view. 
    (...)

module.directive('nameRow', function(YourFactory) {
    (...)
    $scope.setSelected = YourFactory.setSelected;
    (...)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Why does it break when I add scope: { function:'&function'}

Comment: Please provide a plunker